# If else model getattribute in jsp file

Tags: html, jsp

Controller

```
model.addAttribute("ciflength", new String(decodedBytes).length());
```

JSP File

```
if (${ciflength} <10){

<ul></ul>
}else{
<ul></ul>
}
```

I found a few sites that use `<c:if` but it doesn't work and shows an error.

sorry for my bad English and minimum info

Comment: Have you installed jstl library to use <c:if>?

Comment: i try to do this but not work <c:if test="${cif}==16" }">

is this the lib    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> ? @Sanjay

Comment: Yes. You need to provide jstl as a dependency in pom.xml if it is spring application.